# Drawing from another class wont take the right dimensions of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, class, object, jpanel

Ok i have a JPanel such as this one :

```
 public class GUI {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Net");

 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  public GUI()
{
frame.setSize(835,650);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);          
frame.add(panel);
panel.setSize(600,600);
panel.setLocation(215,5);
panel.add(new DrawPlanes(300,300,200,Color.BLACK));}
```

There are some other panels in there tables etc. My main is this one :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ 
@Override
public void run(){
//new GUI();
new GUI().buildTable();

 }

});
```

And there i another class this one :

```
public class DrawPlanes extends JPanel 
{    

private static int centreX, centreY, radius;
private Color colour;

public DrawPlanes()
{
centreX = 300;
centreY = 300;
radius = 200;
colour = Color.BLACK;
}

public DrawPlanes(int centreX,int centreY, int radius, Color colour)
{
this.centreX = centreX;
this.centreY = centreY;
this.radius = radius;
this.colour = colour;

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

super.paintComponent(g);
System.out.println("ppp");
Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;           
g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2F));  
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawOval(centreX - radius , centreY - radius, radius * 2 , radius * 2);
......
}
}
```

Ok so i ve setted the background colour of my panel red to see whats going on the whole panel its red but there is a small grey square where i believe the drawings are. I ve tried to change opaque as there might be an incompatibility issue but nothing changed at all.Any suggestions,is there anything that i m missing?

link of what is the result of

```
 panel.add(new DrawPlanes(300,300,200,Color.BLACK))
```

http://dc626.4shared.com/img/FeYopZC1/s7/142d22f1be0/2013-12-08_142846.png?async&rand=0.9010817544924218

what does the DrawPlanes class draws when i checked it having the main and a panel etc in the DrawPlanes itself http://dc626.4shared.com/img/NPDkiQRJ/s7/142d22f23b0/1451491_586878858047235_191988.jpg?async&rand=0.27479583155781395     .When i apply a layout manager that grey square just moves to the center when i use getPreferredSize overriden or not the whole red panel appears grey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `frame.add(component)` function eventually add your component to frame's content pane which has `BorderLayout` as default layout manager.
- A `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` as default layout which respect component's preferred size.
- As your 'panel' and 'frame' is satisfying above two as a default, size hint with `setSize(Dimension)` or `setBounds(Dimenstion)` to component won't have effect.
- You should provide size hint using `setPreferredSize(Dimenstion)`(*to `DrawPanel` instance of your context*) and if specifying minimum/maximum size is needed `setMinimumSize(Dimenstion)` and `setMaximumSize(Dimenstion)`.
- However it is considered as a better practice to override `getXXXSize(Dimenstion)`: `xxx` represents `Preferred/Minimmum/Maximum` always which allows to adjust size of component with it's content.
- Instead of calling `setSize(Dimension)` on a window it is preferable to call `pack()` at the end of addition of child components.
- We should call `setVisible(true)` after finishing addition of all of the child components and following above point, after `pack()`.

Please, start with the tutorial: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

---

**Edit:**

Let us edit your `GUI()` constructor code and see what happens:

```
public GUI()
{
  frame.setSize(835,650);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  //frame.setVisible(true);   // <<--- call it at the end of the code      
  frame.add(panel);
  //panel.setSize(600,600); <<--- removing set size

  panel.add(new DrawPlanes(300,300,200,Color.BLACK));
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the `DrawPnales` will extend `JComponent`:

```
public class DrawPlanes extends JComponent{
    public DrawPlanes(int centreX,int centreY, int radius, Color colour)
    {
      this.centreX = centreX;
      this.centreY = centreY; 
      this.radius = radius;
      this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

         return new Dimenstion(width, height);
                               // ^ provide your required size 
    }

}
```

If this still doesn't make any sense to you, then please try learning Swing layout managers a little bit further. Otherwise no matter how hard we hit our head on the table, possibly we won't be able to achieve any thing.

Comment: Ok i understand what you re talking about both you and JB Nizet i just had a thorough look at the tutorial and it makes sense what you re telling me, i ve just tried getPreferredSize i ve overrided it i tried GridBagLayout using its constraints i tried MigLayout the only thing i managed to do is to move this little gray square from the top-center to the center no resizing for me.Actually it fits the panel for just a second totally empty and then turns to a little gray square.

Comment: @Renobatio, please attach a picture(upload to a image host and attach the link) to your question depicting your requirement. And for a starter, you can begin with `FlowLayout/BorderLayout`. Not saying that this layout might achieve your goal but it is hard to prefer suitable layout manager before understanding your requiremnt

Comment: i couldnt use more than two links so i posted only those two, hope it works for you.

Comment: You are actually not sharing your complete lay-outing code. Edited the answer. Check if it solves your issue. If it doesn't then please try a little hard to understand swing layout managers first. We can't climb a hill in one shot and not even in one day

Comment: I ve just tried it out , now the whole panel doesnt appear i have a grey area.Seems much more difficult than i thought. :/ Do  you have any more hints to suggest to try out, lets say should i try out FlowLayout Manager and use it constraints?!?!Should i change the whole GUI class and introduce it to FlowLayout (hope not cause i believe something will go wrong that way). I m just afraid that if GridBag and Mig didnt manage to get te job done none of the others will acomplish it :/

Comment: @Renobatio, there is no reason to hurry. Take a look at `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout` first. Your picture actually told me that you can use this two layout managers to achieve whatever you are trying to have. So check them out, practice some of the demo from the tutorial page i have added

Comment: Ok thank you very much i ll let you know of the outcome,thank you for your time.

Comment: i managed it i didnt specify a layout manager so panel used for itself FlowLayout i suppose i extended Drawplanes as JComponent i used getPreferredSize() as you suggested and i ve just added to my JPanel panel.setBounds(215,5,600,600); and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that panels are laid out inside their container using a LayoutManager. The default layout manager of JPanel is a FlowLayout. The FlowLayout uses the preferred width and height of the components it lays out to decide where to place them in the container, and which size they should have. But your DrawPlanes panel doesn't override `getPreferredSize()`, so its preferred size is the default one.

Every time you use `setSize()` on a component or frame, you have a 99.9% probability of doing something wrong. Learn layout managers. If you design a custom component like your DrawPlanes component, which is not just a container for other components, but has a custom `paintComponent()` method, then override `getPreferredSize()`, `getMaximumSize()` and `getMinimumSize()` to tell the layout managers how they should display your component, and to make sure your custom component always has the appropriate size. You never set the size of a JButton, right? That's because the JButton itself decides, based on the text and icon it contains, which size it should have.